# Django How to combine different contexts and pass it to template

Tags: python, django

I am creating a small ToDo App. I don't know how to combine different contexts in one context.

Below You can see that I created three contexts that return different values. The first context counts the number of Plans by date of the Day model. The second context counts the number of completed plans by Day and the third context counts Plans status=deferred

```
class DayStatsListView(ListView):
    model = Day
    queryset = Day.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'all_plan_stats'
    template_name = 'project/stats.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DayStatsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Counting Total Number of Plans by Day
        context['total_plans_count'] = Day.objects.annotate(num_of_plans=Count('plan')) \
            .values('num_of_plans', 'date', 'id') 

        # Counting is_completed=True Plans by Day
        context['num_of_completed_plans'] = Day.objects \
            .filter(plan__is_completed=True) \
            .annotate(num_of_completed_plans=Count('plan__is_completed')) \
            .values('num_of_completed_plans', 'id', 'date')

        # Counting status=deferred Plans by Day
        context['num_of_deferred_plans'] = Day.objects \
            .filter(plan__status='deferred') \
            .annotate(num_of_deferred_plans=Count('plan__is_completed')) \
            .values('num_of_deferred_plans', 'id', 'date')
        return context
```

**models**

```
class Day(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, unique=True)

class Plan(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PLAN_STATUSES, null=True, default='upcoming')
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)

    day = models.ForeignKey(Day, CASCADE, null=True)
```

The question is how can I combine that 3 contexts in one context and pass it to the template so I can easily forloop over it.

I need my these queries should be in one context

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iterate through them in the template, then simply create a dictionary of the keys and the values you want and pass that as the context
E.g.

```
dict1={'num_of_deferred_plans':context['num_of_deferred_plans'],'num_of_completed_plans':context['num_of_completed_plans'],'total_plans_count':context['total_plans_count']}

return render(request, 'some.html', context=dict1 )
```

Once you've constructed this you now have a dict that is iterable in the templates. 
You can do this as follows:

```
{% for key, value in dict1.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it didn't work since render(context=dict) returns error: render() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'template_name'. When I put values of template_name: 'some.html' and request=None, I got another error: **context must be a dict rather than HttpResponse.**

Comment: so did u try `return render (request,'path/some.html',context = dict1)`?

Comment: Is this solved? If so please accept the answer to show that it's been solved.